# Map class to mySql table without using ODB or other frameworks in cpp

Tags: c++, mysql, orm

I read a lot about ODB framework, but sadly can't  implement it due to license issues.

I want to have a class that represents a table.When my application is up, I want to call this function : `Init()` -> it will connect to DB, and another function : `createTables()` -> it will create the tables.

Is there a way to "register" somehow to a class that will include all my classes that should map to mySql tables?

My idea was to create the class, and in its consructor - pass the parameters to another class that will later create all tables.

For example:

```
CalssA_Table
{
 String name;
 Int age;
}

c'tor
{
   RegistrationClass.AddNewTableToCreate("CalssA_Table","String","Int");
}
```

Can anyone advise? Is is a good idea? Are There better ones?
Other ways to implemet it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a global signal and register database initialize functions at static initialization. Having that, you can invoke these function by emitting a signal after connecting to a database.

```
/// Static initialization of classes.
template <typename Class>
class Initializer
{
    public:
    /// Call the static member function Class::initialize()
    Initializer() {
        Class::initialize();
    }
};

// A 'boost signal' or a 'sigc++ signal'  or, ...
Signal& signal_database_initialize() {
    static Signal result;
    return result;
}

// A class interacting with a database
class Table
{
    private:
    friend class Initializer<Table>;
    static void initialize();
};

// In a translation unit
void database_initialize_table() {
    // create tables
}

Initializer<Table> table_initializer;   
void Table::initialize() {
    signal_database_initialize().connect(&database_initialize_table);
}

// Invoke initialization at runtime:
int main()  {
    // Connect to a database
    // ...

    // Initialize database tables:
    signal_database_initialize().emit();
}
```

Note: Here, the signal type is unspecified. It depends on your choice of library.